# How to count rows matching certain conditions within each group?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, count, aggregate-filter

I have more columns in my table `vb10_cartridgedata` but the following two columns are my columns of interest: `NestID`  and `FailCode`. `NestID` can only contain numbers from 1 to 16. I am trying to count how many times did each `NestID` produced each `FailCode`, e.g. how often the `FailCode`=11 showed up for `NestID` =1,  or how many times did the `FailCode`=4 showed up for `NestID`= 4 (for every nest).

| NestID | FailCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 23 |
| 3 | 25 |
| 4 | 32 |
| 4 | 32 |

Conceptually, I am expecting a result similar to this:

| NestID | Ch1 | Ch2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =1 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =1 |
| 2 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =2 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =2 |
| 3 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =3 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =3 |
| 4 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =4 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =4 |
| 5 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =5 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =5 |
| 6 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =6 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =6 |
| 7 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =7 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =7 |
| 8 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =8 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =8 |
| 9 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =9 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID" =9 |
| 10 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =10 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=10 |
| 11 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =11 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=11 |
| 12 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =12 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=12 |
| 13 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =13 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=13 |
| 14 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =14 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=14 |
| 15 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =15 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=15 |
| 16 | count("FailCode"= 10) as "Ch1" where "NestID" =16 | count("FailCode"=23) as "Ch2" where "NestID"=16 |

So, I am expecting to see something like this:

| NestID | Ch1 | Ch 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 33 | 173 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 |
| 4 | 20 | 28 |
| 5 | 0 | 193 |
| 6 | 1 | 27 |
| 7 | 203 | 1 |
| 8 | 13 | 0 |
| 9 | 2 | 261 |
| 10 | 20 | 0 |
| 11 | 173 | 23 |
| 12 | 0 | 53 |
| 13 | 0 | 0 |
| 14 | 0 | 0 |
| 15 | 5 | 14 |
| 16 | 106 | 0 |

I've tried the following, but it's not working for me (please see the picture to see what I am getting):

```
SELECT "NestID",
"FailCode",
count ("FailCode"=23) as "CH1", count ("FailCode"=11) as "CH2"
FROM public.vb10_cartridgedata WHERE "FailCode" != 0 
group by 1, 2;
```

This picture is what I have attempted so far:
[image]

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74306492/how-to-create-my-own-table-based-on-the-count-number-of-numbers-from-a-column

Comment: My bad, I thought there were two different Forums.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)

```
SELECT "NestID",
"FailCode",
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode"=23) as "CH1", 
count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode"=11) as "CH2"
FROM public.vb10_cartridgedata WHERE "FailCode" != 0 
group by 1, 2;
```

Alternatively (e.g. for databases that do not support filtered aggregates) you could use something like this:

```
SELECT "NestID",
"FailCode",
sum (CASE WHEN "FailCode"=23 THEN 1 END) as "CH1", 
sum (CASE WHEN "FailCode"=11 THEN 1 END) as "CH2"
FROM public.vb10_cartridgedata WHERE "FailCode" != 0 
group by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help.
This is what I ended up using:

`SELECT distinct ("NestID"), count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =23) as "CH1", count (*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" =11) as "CH2" FROM public.vb10_cartridgedata group by 1 ;`

[image: Solved]

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)